# Getting the headings from a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I get a list of all the headings in a word document by using VBA?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You mean like this [createOutline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb960898.aspx) function (which actually copy all headings from a source word document into a new word document):

(I believe the `astrHeadings = docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)` function is the key in this program, and should allow you to retrieve what you are asking for)

```
Public Sub CreateOutline()
    Dim docOutline As Word.Document
    Dim docSource As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    
    Dim astrHeadings As Variant
    Dim strText As String
    Dim intLevel As Integer
    Dim intItem As Integer
        
    Set docSource = ActiveDocument
    Set docOutline = Documents.Add
    
    ' Content returns only the main body of the document, not the headers/footer.        
    Set rng = docOutline.Content
    ' GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading) returns an array with references to all headings in the document
    astrHeadings = docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
    
    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
        ' Get the text and the level.
        strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
        intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))
        
        ' Add the text to the document.
        rng.InsertAfter strText & vbNewLine
        
        ' Set the style of the selected range and
        ' then collapse the range for the next entry.
        rng.Style = "Heading " & intLevel
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next intItem
End Sub

Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer
    ' Return the heading level of a header from the
    ' array returned by Word.
    
    ' The number of leading spaces indicates the
    ' outline level (2 spaces per level: H1 has
    ' 0 spaces, H2 has 2 spaces, H3 has 4 spaces.
        
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim intDiff As Integer
    
    ' Get rid of all trailing spaces.
    strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)
    
    ' Trim leading spaces, and then compare with
    ' the original.
    strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)
    
    ' Subtract to find the number of
    ' leading spaces in the original string.
    intDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
    GetLevel = (intDiff / 2) + 1
End Function
```

**UPDATE by @kol on March 6, 2018**

Although `astrHeadings` is an array (`IsArray` returns `True`, and `TypeName` returns `String()`) I get a `type mismatch` error when I try to access its elements in VBScript (v5.8.16384 on Windows 10 Pro 1709 16299.248). This must be a VBScript-specific problem, because I can access the elements if I run the same code in Word's VBA editor. I ended up iterating the lines of the TOC, because it works even from VBScript:

```
For Each Paragraph In Doc.TablesOfContents(1).Range.Paragraphs
  WScript.Echo Paragraph.Range.Text
Next
```

Comment: Except change `int` to `long` to increase macro speed.

Comment: Following @Wikis advice I replace all the `int` of the function by `long` but it gave my an error 9 "subscript out of range". Some of the int could be replace but not all. cf the answer I posted to know which one. (in Word Pro 2013)

Comment: Watch out for truncated headings (`GetCrossReferenceItems`) with this approach. http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/158870-Word-2007-VBA-GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)-returns-truncated-variant-array

Comment: Although `astrHeadings` is an array (`IsArray` returns `True` and `TypeName` returns `String()`) I get a `type mismatch` error when I try to get its elements (VBScript 5.8.16384 on Windows 10 Pro 1709 16299.248).

Comment: @kol 9+ years later, that is possible. I didn't test it in a Windows 10 at the time ;)

Comment: @kol Would more recent answers below work better? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28363925/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41630198/6309)

Comment: @VonC This must be a VBScript-specific problem, because I can access the elements of `astrHeadings` if I run the same code in Word's VBA editor.

Comment: @VonC Regaring the more recent answers: the first one has the same problem, and the second one only adds the TOC. But this gave me an idea: after updating the TOC, I tried to iterate over its paragraphs, and it works even from VBScript :)

Comment: @kol Great! Can you edit this answer to illustrate your approach?

Comment: @VonC Anytime :)

Comment: Hi there, is it possible to get the header it starts with APPENDIX?

Comment: @Alvin567 Twelve years later, I am not sure. That would be a good question on its own.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way to get a list of headings, is to loop through the paragraphs in the document, for example:

```
 Sub ReadPara()

    Dim DocPara As Paragraph

    For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

     If Left(DocPara.Range.Style, Len("Heading")) = "Heading" Then

       Debug.Print DocPara.Range.Text

     End If

    Next


End Sub
```

By the way, I find it is a good idea to remove the final character of the paragraph range. Otherwise, if you send the string to a message box or a document, Word displays an extra control character. For example:

```
Left(DocPara.Range.Text, len(DocPara.Range.Text)-1)
```

Comment: Prefered this to the selected answer - it gave me better results and more flexibility.

Comment: I tried this, but it's unbearably slow... took about 15min processing time to loop through my document (has lots of tables, so there are over 45000 paragraphs)

Answer (score 2):

This macro worked beautifully for me (Word 2010).  I've extended the functionality slightly: now it prompts the user to enter a minimum level, and supresses subheadings below that level.

```
Public Sub CreateOutline()
' from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document
    Dim docOutline As Word.Document
    Dim docSource As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range

    Dim astrHeadings As Variant
    Dim strText As String
    Dim intLevel As Integer
    Dim intItem As Integer
    Dim minLevel As Integer

    Set docSource = ActiveDocument
    Set docOutline = Documents.Add

    minLevel = 1  'levels above this value won't be copied.
    minLevel = CInt(InputBox("This macro will generate a new document that contains only the headers from the existing document. What is the lowest level heading you want?", "2"))

    ' Content returns only the
    ' main body of the document, not
    ' the headers and footer.
    Set rng = docOutline.Content
    astrHeadings = _
     docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
        ' Get the text and the level.
        strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
        intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))

        If intLevel <= minLevel Then

            ' Add the text to the document.
            rng.InsertAfter strText & vbNewLine

            ' Set the style of the selected range and
            ' then collapse the range for the next entry.
            rng.Style = "Heading " & intLevel
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End If
    Next intItem
End Sub

Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer
    ' from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document
    ' Return the heading level of a header from the
    ' array returned by Word.

    ' The number of leading spaces indicates the
    ' outline level (2 spaces per level: H1 has
    ' 0 spaces, H2 has 2 spaces, H3 has 4 spaces.

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim intDiff As Integer

    ' Get rid of all trailing spaces.
    strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)

    ' Trim leading spaces, and then compare with
    ' the original.
    strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)

    ' Subtract to find the number of
    ' leading spaces in the original string.
    intDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
    GetLevel = (intDiff / 2) + 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest method for extracting of all headings (to LEVEL5).

```
Sub EXTRACT_HDNGS()
Dim WDApp As Word.Application    'WORD APP
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document       'WORD DOC

Set WDApp = Word.Application
Set WDDoc = WDApp.ActiveDocument

For Head_n = 1 To 5
Head = ("Heading " & Head_n)
WDApp.Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove

    Do
       With WDApp.selection
      .MoveStart Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1    
      .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
       End with
        With WDApp.Selection.Find
          .ClearFormatting:          .text = "":     
          .MatchWildcards = False:   .Forward = True
          .Style = WDDoc.Styles(Head)
         If .Execute = False Then GoTo Level_exit
            .ClearFormatting
        End With

       Heading_txt = RemoveSpecialChar(WDApp.Selection.Range.text, 1):              Debug.Print Heading_txt
       Heading_lvl = WDApp.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber:              Debug.Print Heading_lvl
       Heading_lne = WDDoc.Range(0, WDApp.Selection.Range.End).Paragraphs.Count:    Debug.Print Heading_lne
       Heading_pge = WDApp.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber):            Debug.Print Heading_pge

       If Wdapp.Selection.Style = "Heading 1" Then GoTo Level_exit
       Wdapp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
   Loop
Level_exit:
Next Head_n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Wikis comment on VonC answer, here is the code that worked for me. It makes the function faster.

```
Public Sub CopyHeadingsInNewDoc()
    Dim docOutline As Word.Document
    Dim docSource As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range

    Dim astrHeadings As Variant
    Dim strText As String
    Dim longLevel As Integer
    Dim longItem As Integer

    Set docSource = ActiveDocument
    Set docOutline = Documents.Add

    ' Content returns only the
    ' main body of the document, not
    ' the headers and footer.
    Set rng = docOutline.Content
    astrHeadings = _
     docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
        ' Get the text and the level.
        strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
        intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))

        ' Add the text to the document.
        rng.InsertAfter strText & vbNewLine

        ' Set the style of the selected range and
        ' then collapse the range for the next entry.
        rng.Style = "Heading " & intLevel
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next intItem
End Sub

Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer
    ' Return the heading level of a header from the
    ' array returned by Word.

    ' The number of leading spaces indicates the
    ' outline level (2 spaces per level: H1 has
    ' 0 spaces, H2 has 2 spaces, H3 has 4 spaces.

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim longDiff As Integer

    ' Get rid of all trailing spaces.
    strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)

    ' Trim leading spaces, and then compare with
    ' the original.
    strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)

    ' Subtract to find the number of
    ' leading spaces in the original string.
    longDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
    GetLevel = (longDiff / 2) + 1
End Function
```

Comment: Interesting take on my 6+ years old answer. +1

Comment: I could have edited your answer, but because you haven't edited following Wikis comment, I wasn't sure it would be a good idea! (am still a newbie in VBA)

Comment: @VonC Btw is there a way to only select Headings 1 and 2 with this function (you can edit my answer to reflect the change if you want ;-) !)

Answer (score 1):

Why reinventing the wheel so many times?!?

A "list of all headings" is just the standard Word index of document!

This is what I got by recording a macro while adding index to the document:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _
        RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
        UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
        UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _
        LowerHeadingLevel:=5, _
        IncludePageNumbers:=True, _
        AddedStyles:="", _
        UseHyperlinks:=True, _
        HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, _
        UseOutlineLevels:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a Table of Contents in the doc and copy that. This separates out the para ref from the title, which is handy if you need to present that in another context.
If you do not want the ToC in your doc, just delete that after the Copy n Paste. JK.