# No Dangling Word Headings Between Page Breaks?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Does anyone have a good VBA way (or perhaps there is an MS Word setting I can't find) to make sure that Word headings do not dangle at the end of a page.

For example, assume that the numbers on the left are page numbers.

```
1  This is the second to last line on the page.
1  HEADING 1
2  This text starts page two
```

What I want to do is automatically move Heading 1 down so that:

```
1  This is the second to last line on the page.
1  
2  HEADING 1
2  This text starts page two
```

I am familiar with this question:
[Getting the headings from a Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want "keep with next" (Paragraph formatting > Line and Page breaks tab).

Possibly also of interest:  Widow/Orphan control

Comment: For posterity's sake on a 15-year-old answer... Be sure, though, that you're spacing the very next paragraph by setting the style for Heading 1 to add space, not by hitting the [Enter] key (^p or ^13) twice! The heading will stay with the "blank" paragraph that follows, and the words in the actual paragraph will break to page 2.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the dangling header scenario you describe only occurs when the font is set manually and the Style is initially left at Normal.

If you set the Style on the headings to be Heading 1, 2, or 3, it will prevent the header from being left at the bottom of the page by itself.

If you decide to change your document to use Style-based headers, you will want to alter the Heading styles in the Styles and Formatting window.
To open that window, either:

- Click the `Styles and Formatting` button on the toolbar (the "A" button to the left of the Font selector), or
- Open it via the `Format > Styles and Formatting...` menu option.

Then you can mouse over the available styles, select the dropdown arrow, click `Modify...`, and change the styles to your liking.

(Tested with Word 2003.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. When you define your styles be sure to set TRUE for .ParagraphFormat.KeepTogheter or .ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext