# Extract Headings and Pagenumber of Table of Contents of a Word Document with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Basically what we have here

[Getting the headings from a Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document)

```
Public Sub CreateOutline()
    Dim docOutline As Word.Document
    Dim docSource As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range

    Dim astrHeadings As Variant
    Dim strText As String
    Dim intLevel As Integer
    Dim intItem As Integer

    Set docSource = ActiveDocument
    Set docOutline = Documents.Add

    ' Content returns only the
    ' main body of the document, not
    ' the headers and footer.
    Set rng = docOutline.Content
    astrHeadings = _
     docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
        ' Get the text and the level.
        strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
        intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))

        ' Add the text to the document.
        rng.InsertAfter strText & vbNewLine

        ' Set the style of the selected range and
        ' then collapse the range for the next entry.
        rng.Style = "Heading " & intLevel
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next intItem
End Sub

Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer
    ' Return the heading level of a header from the
    ' array returned by Word.

    ' The number of leading spaces indicates the
    ' outline level (2 spaces per level: H1 has
    ' 0 spaces, H2 has 2 spaces, H3 has 4 spaces.

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim intDiff As Integer

    ' Get rid of all trailing spaces.
    strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)

    ' Trim leading spaces, and then compare with
    ' the original.
    strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)

    ' Subtract to find the number of
    ' leading spaces in the original string.
    intDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
    GetLevel = (intDiff / 2) + 1
End Function
```

but I need the page number for each heading too.

I tried doing a search for each heading, select the search result and retrieve the wdActiveEndPageNumber.

This didn't work, was slow and is sure an ugly approach.

I'd like to paste the found stuff into another word document like:
rng.InsertAfter "Page: " & pageNum & " Header: " & strText & vbNewLine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may not understand the question, then, but this code goes through the document, looking for lines that are only headers and gets the page its on.

```
Public Sub SeeHeadingPageNumber()
    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler

    Dim sourceDocument As Document
    Set sourceDocument = ActiveDocument

    Dim myPara As Paragraph
    For Each myPara In sourceDocument.Paragraphs
        myPara.Range.Select 'For debug only
        If InStr(LCase$(myPara.Range.Style.NameLocal), LCase$("heading")) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print myPara.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        End If

        DoEvents
    Next

    Exit Sub

MyErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "SeeHeadingPageNumber" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Err = " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. This is probably the fastest/easiest way to go about this. If it were me, I'd accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Table of Content field. The following code dissects a TOC and gives you the item, page number and style. You might have to parse each string to get the exact info or formatting you need.

```
Public Sub SeeTOCInfo()
    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler

    Dim sourceDocument As Document
    Set sourceDocument = ActiveDocument

    Dim myField As Field
    For Each myField In sourceDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Range.Fields
        Debug.Print Replace(myField.Result.Text, Chr(13), "-") & " " & " Type: " & myField.Type
        If Not myField.Result.Style Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print myField.Result.Style
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next

    Exit Sub

MyErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "SeeTOCInfo" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Err = " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds good but I might have to extend the retrieved information later on and I don't have to seem that type of "freedom" with a TOC :/

Answer (score 0):

This will insert the page number of the referenced Heading:

```
rng.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeHeading, _
            ReferenceKind:=wdPageNumber, ReferenceItem:=intItem
```

But only works if you're inserting in the same document. You could insert in the current document and then cut/paste out to a new document.

Comment: This sounds good, but how exactly would the insert and cut/paste process look a like? Sorry I'm a real beginner regarding VBA.