# Table of Content, VBA,

Tags: vba, tableofcontents

I have a word document which has a table of content and a few paragraphs for each of the items in table of content. Below is an example:
                         Table of Content
item Number            item Details              Page Number
1.              Account Details                      ....1
1.1                    Account History               ....1
1.2                    Current Item in Progress      ....2
2.                     Stakeholder                   ....3
3.              Timelines etc                        ....4

Each of these headers have a paragraph on page numbers mentioned. I need to get these paragraphs for say stakeholders.

I am able to get to the table of contents but not individual  items and paragraphs. Below is the code i have written so far

```
Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordapp.Documents.Open filepath
wordapp.Visible = True
'MsgBox (wordapp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents)

with wordapp
For Each TOC In wordapp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
MsgBox (TOC.Item)
Next
End With
```

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628222/extract-headings-and-pagenumber-of-table-of-contents-of-a-word-document-with-vba) is a similar question

Comment: Hi Harvey, Thanks. :) This gave me clue and solved the problem..