# How to select all headings in Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm very new to VBA and I have a long Word file with lots of headings. Any tips how to write a macro that selects all the headings in the file and changes the formatting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: posible duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see it before, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to select all the headings and change the formatting using VBA. Just modify the styles that are applied to the headings (Heading1, Heading2, Heading3 etc.)

Kem