# Word VBA heading text cut short and function produces reversed results when called from Sub

Tags: vba, ms-word

Sorry for the two fold question in one post.

This indirectly relates to a question I posted recently here: [vba: return page number from selection.find using text from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327813/vba-return-page-number-from-selection-find-using-text-from-array) which was solved

Program purpose:

Firstly: add a footer with custom page numbers to documents (i.e. 0.0.0, Chapter.Section,Page representative) in a selected folder and sub folders.

Secondly: create a TOC with the custom page numbers saved as roottoc.docx in the root folder selected.

I now have two new problems before I can fully clean and finally put this to bed, I will post the full code at the end of this post.

**Solved** First of all, from what I have discovered and just read elsewhere too the `getCrossReferenceItems(refTypeHeading)` method will only return the text upto a certain length from what of finds. I have some pretty long headings which means this is quite an annoyance for the purpose of my code. So the first question I have is is there something I can do with the `getCrossReferenceItems(refTypeHeading)` method to force it to collect the full text from any referenced headings or is there an alternative way round this problem.

**Solved** Secondly the `createOutline()` function when called in `ChooseFolder()` produces the correct results but in reverse order, could someone point the way on this one too please.

Unfortunately the actual results I am recieving will be difficulty to exactly replicate but if a folder is made containing a couple of documents with various headings. The directory name should be the the same as what is in the Unit Array i.e. Unit(1) "Unit 1", the file names are made up of two parts i.e. Unit(1) & " " & Criteria(1) & ext becoming "Unit 1 p1.docx" etc, the arrays **Unit** and **Criteria** are in the `ChooseFolder` Sub. **chapArr** is a numerical representative of the **Unit** array contents soley for my page numbering system, I used another array because of laziness at this point in time. I could have used some other method on the Unit array to achieve the same result which I might look at when cleaning up.

When running the ChooseFolder Sub if the new folder with documents in is located in My Document then **My Documents** will be the folder to locate and select in the file dialogue window. This should produce results that are similar and will give an example of what I am talking about.

Complete code:

```
Public Sub ChooseFolder()
  'Declare Variables
    '|Applications|
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    '|Strings|
    Dim chapNum As String
    Dim sResult As String
    Dim Filepath As String
    Dim strText As String
    Dim StrChapSec As String
    '|Integers|
    Dim secNum As Integer
    Dim AckTime As Integer
    Dim FolderChosen As Integer
    '|Arrays|
    Dim Unit() As Variant
    Dim ChapArray() As Variant
    Dim Criteria() As Variant
    '|Ranges|
    Dim rng As Range
    '|Objects|
    Dim InfoBox As Object
    '|Dialogs|
    Dim fd As FileDialog
  'Constants
    Const ext = ".docx"
  'Set Variable Values
    secNum = 0 'Set Section number start value
    AckTime = 1 'Set the message box to close after 1 seconds
    Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 'Set shell object
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Set file dialog object
    FolderChosen = fd.Show 'Display file dialogue
  'Set Array Values
  'ToDo: create form to set values for Arrays
    'Folder names
    Unit = Array("Unit 1", "Unit 2")
    'Chapter Numbers
    chapArr = Array("1", "2")
    'Document names
    Criteria = Array("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "D1", "D2", "D3")

    If FolderChosen <> -1 Then
        'didn't choose anything (clicked on CANCEL)
        MsgBox "You chose cancel"
    Else
        'Set sResult equal to selected file/folder in file dialogue
        sResult = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    ' Loop through unit array items
    For i = LBound(Unit) To UBound(Unit)
        unitName = Unit(i)
        ' Test unit folder being looked at and concatenate sResult with
        ' unitName delimited with "\"
        If unitName = "Unit 105" Then
            Filepath = sResult & "\unit 9"
        Else
            Filepath = sResult & "\" & unitName
        End If
        ' Loop through criteria array items
        For j = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)
            criteriaName = Criteria(j)
            ' Set thisFile equal to full file path
            thisfile = Filepath & "\" & unitName & " " & criteriaName & ext 'Create file name by concatenating filePath with "space" criteriaName and ext
            ' Test if file exists
            If File_Exists(thisfile) = True Then
                ' If file exists do something (i.e. process number of pages/modify document start page number)
                ' Inform user of file being processed and close popup after 3 seconds
                Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Processing file - " & thisfile, AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)
                    Case 1, -1
                End Select
                ' Open document in word using generated filePath in read/write mode
                ' Process first section footer page number and amend to start as intPages (total pages)  + 1
                Set doc = Documents.Open(thisfile)
                With doc
                    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
                        chapNum = chapArr(i)
                        secNum = secNum + 1
                        ' Retrieve current footer text
                        strText = .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
                        .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
                        ' Set first page footer text to original text
                        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = strText
                        ' Set other pages footer text
                        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = Date & vbTab & "Author: Robert Ells" & vbTab & chapNum & "." & secNum & "."
                        Set rng = .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Duplicate
                        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                        rng.InsertBefore "{PAGE}"
                        TextToFields rng
                    End With
                    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers.StartingNumber = 1
                    Selection.Fields.Update
                    Hide_Field_Codes
                    ActiveDocument.Save
                    CreateOutline sResult, chapNum & "." & secNum & "."
                End With
            Else
                'If file doesn't exist do something else (inform of non existant document and close popup after 3 seconds
                Select Case InfoBox.Popup("File: " & thisfile & " - Does not exist", AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)
                    Case 1, -1
                End Select
            End If

        Next
        Filepath = ""
        secNum = 0
    Next
End Sub

Private Function TextToFields(rng1 As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim lFldStarts() As Long

    Set rng2 = rng1.Duplicate
    rng1.Document.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True

    For Each c In rng1.Characters
        DoEvents
        Select Case c.Text
            Case "{"
                ReDim Preserve lFldStarts(f)
                lFldStarts(f) = c.Start
                f = f + 1
            Case "}"
                f = f - 1
                If f = 0 Then
                    rng2.Start = lFldStarts(f)
                    rng2.End = c.End
                    rng2.Characters.Last.Delete '{
                    rng2.Characters.First.Delete '}
                    Set fld = rng2.Fields.Add(rng2, , , False)
                    Set rng2 = fld.Code
                    TextToFields fld.Code
                End If
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next c
    rng2.Expand wdStory
    rng2.Fields.Update
    rng1.Document.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
End Function

Private Function CreateOutline(Filepath, pgNum)
' from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document
  'Declare Variables
    '|Applications|
    Dim App As Word.Application
    Dim docSource As Word.Document
    Dim docOutLine As Word.Document
    '|Strings|
    Dim strText As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    '|Integers|
    Dim intLevel As Integer
    Dim intItem As Integer
    Dim minLevel As Integer
    '|Arrays|
    Dim strFootNum() As Integer
    '|Ranges|
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    '|Variants|
    Dim astrHeadings As Variant
    Dim tabStops As Variant
  'Set Variable values
    Set docSource = ActiveDocument
    If Not FileLocked(Filepath & "\" & "roottoc.docx") Then
        If File_Exists(Filepath & "\" & "roottoc.docx") Then
            Set docOutLine = Documents.Open(Filepath & "\" & "roottoc.docx", ReadOnly:=False)
        Else
            Set docOutLine = Document.Add
        End If
    End If

    ' Content returns only the
    ' main body of the document, not
    ' the headers and footer.
    Set rng = docOutLine.Content

    minLevel = 5  'levels above this value won't be copied.

    astrHeadings = returnHeaderText(docSource) 'docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

    docSource.Select
    ReDim strFootNum(0 To UBound(astrHeadings))
    For i = 1 To UBound(astrHeadings)
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = Trim(astrHeadings(i))
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        End With

        If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then
            strFootNum(i) = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Else
            MsgBox "No selection found", vbOKOnly 'Or whatever you want to do if it's not found'
        End If
        Selection.Move
    Next

    docOutLine.Select
    With Selection.Paragraphs.tabStops
        '.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(2), Alignment:=wdAlignTabLeft
        .Add Position:=InchesToPoints(6), Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight, Leader:=wdTabLeaderDots
    End With

    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
        ' Get the text and the level.
        ' strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
        intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))
        ' Test which heading is selected and indent accordingly
        If intLevel <= minLevel Then
                If intLevel = "1" Then
                    strText = " " & Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem)) & vbTab & pgNum & strFootNum(intItem) & vbCr
                End If
                If intLevel = "2" Then
                    strText = "   " & Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem)) & vbTab & pgNum & strFootNum(intItem) & vbCr
                End If
                If intLevel = "3" Then
                    strText = "      " & Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem)) & vbTab & pgNum & strFootNum(intItem) & vbCr
                End If
                If intLevel = "4" Then
                    strText = "         " & Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem)) & vbTab & pgNum & strFootNum(intItem) & vbCr
                End If
                If intLevel = "5" Then
                    strText = "            " & Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem)) & vbTab & pgNum & strFootNum(intItem) & vbCr
                End If
            ' Add the text to the document.
            rng.Collapse (False)
            rng.InsertAfter strText & vbLf
            docOutLine.SelectAllEditableRanges
            ' tab stop to set at 15.24 cm
            'With Selection.Paragraphs.tabStops
            '    .Add Position:=InchesToPoints(6), _
            '    Leader:=wdTabLeaderDots, Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight
            '    .Add Position:=InchesToPoints(2), Alignment:=wdAlignTabCenter
            'End With
            rng.Collapse (False)
        End If
    Next intItem
    docSource.Close
    docOutLine.Save
    docOutLine.Close
End Function

Function returnHeaderText(doc As Word.Document) As Variant
    Dim returnArray() As Variant
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
        If Left(para.Style, 7) = "Heading" Then
            ReDim Preserve returnArray(i)
            returnArray(i) = para.Range.Text
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    returnHeaderText = returnArray
End Function

Function FileLocked(strFileName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   ' If the file is already opened by another process,
   ' and the specified type of access is not allowed,
   ' the Open operation fails and an error occurs.
   Open strFileName For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #1
   Close #1
   ' If an error occurs, the document is currently open.
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ' Display the error number and description.
      MsgBox "Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " - " & Err.Description
      FileLocked = True
      Err.Clear
   End If
End Function


Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer
    ' from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document
    ' Return the heading level of a header from the
    ' array returned by Word.

    ' The number of leading spaces indicates the
    ' outline level (2 spaces per level: H1 has
    ' 0 spaces, H2 has 2 spaces, H3 has 4 spaces.

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim intDiff As Integer

    ' Get rid of all trailing spaces.
    strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)

    ' Trim leading spaces, and then compare with
    ' the original.
    strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)

    ' Subtract to find the number of
    ' leading spaces in the original string.
    intDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
    GetLevel = (intDiff / 2) + 1
End Function

Private Function File_Exists(ByVal sPathName As String, Optional Directory As Boolean) As Boolean
    'Returns True if the passed sPathName exist
    'Otherwise returns False
    On Error Resume Next
    If sPathName <> "" Then
        If IsMissing(Directory) Or Directory = False Then
            File_Exists = (Dir$(sPathName) <> "")
        Else
            File_Exists = (Dir$(sPathName, vbDirectory) <> "")
        End If
    End If
End Function

Sub Hide_Field_Codes()
    Application.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
End Sub
```

Kevin's Solutions:

**Question part 1, Answer**

I thought initially that something went wrong when I added your function, but it was due to a blank heading on the following line after the actual heading in the documents. I suppose an `If` statement to test if there is text present could solve this.  :-)

I haven't tested this bit yet (due to being tired), but if the heading is inline with normal text, would this function pick up only the heading or both heading and normal text?

**Question part 2, Answer**

Just worked, although with one niggle (the list produced is no longer indented as desired in the main `CreateOutline` function). Time is getting on now so will have to pick this up again tomorrow :-)

Thanks yet again kevin, this is where I should have concentrated more during programming at uni instead of thinking about the pub.

Phil :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome back!  :-)

For the reversed data from the CreateOutline function - change your Collapse function to have a `false` parameter.  Collapse defaults to putting the cursor at the beginning of the selection, but this will put it at the end so you're adding to the end of the doc instead of the beginning:

```
' Add the text to the document.
rng.Collapse(False) 'HERE'
rng.InsertAfter strText & vbLf
docOutLine.SelectAllEditableRanges
rng.Collapse(False) 'AND HERE'
```

For the CrossReferenceItems issue, try this and let me know if there's any data missing from what it returns.  Call this instead of the CrossReferenceItems method:

```
Function returnHeaderText(doc As Word.Document) As Variant
    Dim returnArray() As Variant
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
        If Left(para.Style, 7) = "Heading" Then
            ReDim Preserve returnArray(i)
            returnArray(i) = para.Range.Text
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    returnHeaderText = returnArray
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've got a bit of a couple of problems with the returnHeaderText function, for the most part it works a treat. Firstly it returns even empty headings, i've tried adding a test but failed. Secondly I need access to the heading style to know how much to indent the returned text by. Thanks Phil.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem - by Heading Style, you mean "Heading 1", "Heading 2", etc?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've got these problems sort out now and begun cleaning up my code, loosing unnecessary code, adding comments and tidying up the formatting in the output. I have something as an after thought though, regarding updating the output without re-writing the whole output. I will see if I can figure this out first and if not I will post this as a new question along with my updated and cleaned code. you've been a great help with my troubles thanks and regards Phil