# MS Word + VBA + RegExp: Get Page Number of Match

Tags: regex, ms-word, page-numbering

Is that possible? Probably not? How can I then find all exact occurrences of a match and the according page numbers?

EDIT:

I have the regex working properly. What I need is for each match to get all the pages it appears on.

Example:

```
regex = \b\d{3}\b

123 appears on page 1,4,20
243 appear on page 3,5,7
523 appears on page 9
```

How can I get that information (all the pages a match occurs on?)

This is for creating some kind of index automatically.

EDIT 2:

I got a basic working version, snippet:

```
Set Matches = regExp.Execute(ActiveDocument.range.Text)

For Each Match In Matches    
    Set range = ActiveDocument.range(Match.FirstIndex, Match.FirstIndex + Len(Match.Value))    
    page = range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
```

The problem is that Match.FirstIndex does not always point to the first character of the match in ActiveDocument.range. Word tables mess this up as ActiveDocument.range.Text contains characters that are not on the text put represent something in the table.

Comment: Why do you need a regex to match page number? Can you explain a bit more? You can `find` page numbers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327813/vba-return-page-number-from-selection-find-using-text-from-array

Comment: @bonCodigo The OP needs to match *something* and then retrieve the according page number.

Comment: @Tomalak then it makes sense...otherwise I was wondering..then OP has to tell us what wants to match.... :$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be rather complex and I can't say if my solution works for any document. The main issue is as indicated in the Question, that RegexMatch.FirstIndex can not be used to determine were the actually Match is within the MS Word Document. This is due to the fact that regex matching is done on range.Text property (String) and that string just contains different amount of characters than the range object does and hence Indexes don't match.

So my solution is for each match, I do a Find in the whole document for that match. the find methods gives a Range object from which the correct page can be determined.

In my special case a match could be the same thing also different value. Example: `343`in my case would be the same as `Prefix-343`. A second issue was that the matches must be sorted eg `123`before `324`regardless which one occurs first in the document.

If you require the Sort Functionality you will also need the following to "modules":

SortDictionary Function:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm

Module "modQSortInPlace":

http://www.cpearson.com/Zips/modQSortInPlace.zip

If no sort is needed you don't need them but you need to remove the according function call `SortDictionary Dict, True`from my code.

Now to my code. Soem parts you can remove, especially the formatting one. This is specific to my case. Also if your match is "unique", eg. not prefix or so you can simplify the code too. You will need to reference the "Microsoft Scripting Library".

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractRNumbers()

    Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

    Dim regExp, Match, Matches
    Dim rNumber As String
    Dim range As range

    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regExp.Pattern = "\b(R-)?\d{2}-\d{4,5}(-\d)?\b"
    regExp.IgnoreCase = False
    regExp.Global = True

    ' determine main section, only extract R-Numbers from main section
    ' and not the Table of contents as example
    ' main section = section with most characters

    Dim section As section
    Dim maxSectionSize As Long
    Dim sectionSize As Long
    Dim sectionIndex As Integer
    Dim currentIndex As Integer
    maxSectionSize = 0
    currentIndex = 1
    For Each section In ActiveDocument.Sections
        sectionSize = Len(section.range.text)
        If sectionSize > maxSectionSize Then
            maxSectionSize = sectionSize
            sectionIndex = currentIndex
        End If
        currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
    Next


    Set Matches = regExp.Execute(ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionIndex).range.text)


    For Each Match In Matches

        ' If the Document contains Tables, ActiveDocument.range.Text will contain
        ' BEL charachters (chr(7)) that probably define the table structure. The issue
        ' is that then Match.FirstIndex does not point to the actual first charachter
        ' of a Match in the Document.
        ' Also there are other things (unknwon) that lead to the same issue, eg.
        ' Match.FirstIndex can not be used to find the actual "matching word" within the
        ' document. Because of that below commented apporach does not work on a generic document

        '   Set range = ActiveDocument.range(Match.FirstIndex, Match.FirstIndex + Len(Match.Value))
        '   page = range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

        ' Maybe there is a simpler solution but this works more or less
        ' the exception beign tables again. see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274003

        ' After a match is found the whole document is searched using the find method.
        ' For each find result the page number is put into an array (if it is not in the array yet)
        ' Then the match is formatted properly.
        ' After formatting, it is checked if the match was previously already found
        '
        '   If not, we add a new entry to the dictionary (key = formatted match, value = array of page numbers)
        '
        '   If match was already found before (but potentially in a different format! eg R-87-1000 vs 87-1000 as example),
        '   all additional pages are added to the already found pages.

        Set range = ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionIndex).range
        With range.Find
            .text = Match.Value
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
        End With

        Dim page As Variant
        Dim pages() As Integer
        Dim index As Integer
        index = 0
        ReDim pages(0)

        Do While range.Find.Execute() = True
            page = range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            If Not IsInArray(page, pages) Then
                ReDim Preserve pages(index)
                pages(index) = page
                index = index + 1
            End If
        Loop

        ' FORMAT TO PROPER R-NUMBER: This is specific to my case
        rNumber = Match.Value
        If Not rNumber Like "R-*" Then
         rNumber = "R-" & rNumber
        End If
        ' remove possible batch number as r-number
        If Len(rNumber) > 11 Then
            rNumber = Left(rNumber, Len(rNumber) - 2)
        End If
        ' END FORMAT

        If Not Dict.Exists(rNumber) Then
            Dict.Add rNumber, pages
        Else
            Dim existingPages() As Integer
            existingPages = Dict(rNumber)
            For Each page In pages
                If Not IsInArray(page, existingPages) Then
                    ' add additonal pages. this means that the previous match
                    ' was formatted different, eg R-87-1000 vs 87-1000 as example
                    ReDim Preserve existingPages(UBound(existingPages) + 1)
                    existingPages(UBound(existingPages)) = page
                    Dict(rNumber) = existingPages
                End If
            Next
        End If

    Next
    'sort dictionary by key (R-Number)
    SortDictionary Dict, True
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim stream
    ' Create a TextStream.
    Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.Name & "-rNumbers.txt", True)

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim output As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each key In Dict.Keys()
        output = key & vbTab
        pages = Dict(key)
        For i = LBound(pages) To UBound(pages)
            output = output & pages(i) & ", "
        Next
        output = Left(output, Len(output) - 2)
        stream.WriteLine output        
    Next
    Set Dict = Nothing
    stream.Close
End Sub

Private Function IsInArray(page As Variant, pages As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    IsInArray = False
    For i = LBound(pages) To UBound(pages)
        If pages(i) = page Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this probably fits better in SuperUser.

The answer to the question is "yes."

```
Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
```

The above property in VBA will get you the page number of a selection.

Also, [VBA can do some regular expression work](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html).

Comment: @beginner_ Do you have an example of what you've tried so far? Or at least the regular expression you have and the sort of output you're looking for?