# Extracting string values containing a certain key word from Word doc to Excel with the page number

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA and trying to extract some string values that contain a certain key word from a Word document to Excel. For example, there are country codes such as USA.001.01.033592 and I want to extract all the string values look like the country code from the word doc and collect them into a Excel spreadsheet.

The country codes I'm looking at as a format of

1. USA.xxx.xx.xxxxxx
2. JPA.xxx.xx.xxxxxx
3. FRA.xxx.xx.xxxxxx
   The Xs represent numbers and the problem is theses codes are in the main body paragraphs, tables within the paragraphs, and the footnotes. Also, when I retrieve the codes, I also want to extract the page number.

Is there any way I can extract the data I want from the main paragraphs, tables, and footnotes at once with their page number?

I have a rough draft of my code but it's not working at all. Could anyone please help?

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Footnotes()

    Dim appExcel As Object
    Dim objSheet As Object
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim intRowCount As Integer
    intRowCount = 1
    Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range

    With aRange.Find
    Do
        .Text = "USA." or "JPA." or "FRA."
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
            aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
            aRange.Copy
            aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            If objSheet Is Nothing Then
               Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
               Set objSheet = appExcel.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Footnotes.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
               intRowCount = 1
            End If
            objSheet.Cells(intRowCount, 1).Select
            objSheet.Paste
            intRowCount = intRowCount + 1
        End If
        Loop While .Found
    End With

    If Not objSheet Is Nothing Then
    appExcel.workbooks(1).Close True
    appExcel.Quit
    Set objSheet = Nothing
    Set appExcel = Nothing
    End If
    Set aRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

currently, I'm trying to use VBA from the word document but if it's better to start from the excel file please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vba: return page number from selection.find using text from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327813/vba-return-page-number-from-selection-find-using-text-from-array)

Answer (score 0):

As you have a distinct pattern to search for you can use Word's `Find` with wildcards. There is a [good reference](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm) for that at the Word MVP website. This will enable `Find` to return the entire string that you are looking for without needing to extend the found range.

Once you have the found range you can then retrieve the text to pass to Excel and obtain the page number using the `Information` property.

A Word document consists of a number of parts referred to as [`StoryRanges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.storyranges). Whilst tables are just part of the range that contains them, footnotes are contained in a separate StoryRange. The code below loops through the StoryRanges and checks which [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdstorytype) the current one is. I have done it this way so that you can add other types if you need to.

It wasn't stated in your question what you wanted to do with the page number so you'll need to modify the code below for that.

```
Sub Footnotes()

   Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
   Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim findRange As Range
   Dim intRowCount As Integer
   Dim pageNum As Long
   
   If objSheet Is Nothing Then
      Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      Set objSheet = appExcel.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Footnotes.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
   End If
   intRowCount = 2
   
   'Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Range
   For Each findRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
      With findRange.Find
         .Text = "[UJF][PRS]A.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{6}"
         .MatchWildcards = True
         Do While .Execute = True
            pageNum = CLng(findRange.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber))
            objSheet.Cells(intRowCount, 1).Value = findRange.Text
            objSheet.Cells(intRowCount, 2).Value = pageNum
            intRowCount = intRowCount + 1
            findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
         Loop
      End With
   Next findRange

   If Not objSheet Is Nothing Then
      appExcel.workbooks(1).Close True
      appExcel.Quit
      Set objSheet = Nothing
      Set appExcel = Nothing
   End If
   Set findRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT:
The code above only finds the country codes listed in the question. To find any country code change `Find.Text` to "[A-Z]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{6}"

Comment: Hi Timothy. Thank you so much. What I wanted to do with the page numbers was, I just wanted to store them in a separate column. So there are two different columns "Data" and "Page Num". Which part should I modify to do that? Also with the current code, it breaks at "objSheet.Cells(intRowCount, 1).Range.Value = findRange.Text". It says wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Comment: @alexsmith5123 - please see edited code. Note that you need to start `intRowCount` from 2 to avoid your column headings.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain why it needs "findRagne.Collapse wdCollapseEnd in the while loop?

Comment: @alexsmith5123 - when a match is found `Find` redefines the range to the range of the found item. If you didn't collapse the range `Find` would not continue past that match.