# VBA find and replace in word. Replacing space with non-breaking space between number and word

Tags: excel, vba, search, replace, ms-word

I hope you can help me.
I have three questions:

1. In my coding below I am trying to replace "([0-9])( )([A-Za-zÆæØøÅå])" with "\1^s\3", but the result allways ends like \1\3^2 or as example "3 A" would become "3A(non-breaking space)", but what I want is "3(non-breaking space)A".
2. Is there any way I can make ([A-Za-zÆæØøÅå]) to a dynamic word? I have a list of word I want to use instead. Example "3 mg" to "3(non-breaking space)mg" or "1 kilo" to "1(non-breaking space)kilo".
3. Is there any way I can make a search and replace, where I only replace the "space" with a "non-breaking space" and not the wildcards. The above solution will result in the wildcards being replaced by themselves, this is usually not a problem, but since I am doing this in a dokument that is in tracked changed it will be visable.

```
Sub NonBreakingSpace(ByVal wordApp As Object, ByVal wordDoc As Object, ByVal myStoryRange As Object)


'With Worksheets("sheet1")
'For Each cell In Range("A3:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
   ' Find1 = cell.Value
   ' Replace1 = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    
    For Each myStoryRange In wordDoc.StoryRanges
          With myStoryRange.Find
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Text = "([0-9])( )([A-Za-zÆæØøÅå])"
            .Forward = True
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .Replacement.Text = "\1^2\3"
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Next myStoryRange
'Next cell
'End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ^s is a non-breaking space, not ^2. You can easily find the symbols required by looking at the text in the advance Find dialog in Word.
2. Just replace the wildcard characters with a variable containing the word you are looking for. You will need to run a separate search for each Word.
3. Yes, but you won't be able to use Replace. You will need to write code to process each match found. There are numerous examples that show how to do this on SO, e.g. [Extracting string values containing a certain key word from Word doc to Excel with the page number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951727/extracting-string-values-containing-a-certain-key-word-from-word-doc-to-excel-wi/63953358#63953358)

Comment: Dear Timothy,
Thanks alot for taking you time to look at my questions.
For question number 1, I have changed the replacement to "\1^2\3", but I get the same problem. If I use the code on "3 A" it would become "3A(non-breaking space)", but what I want is "3(non-breaking space)A".

Comment: @Casper - I suggest you re-read point 1 of my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry I do mean "\1^s\2". 
My full search and replace code is now:

    For Each myStoryRange In wordDoc.StoryRanges
          With myStoryRange.Find
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Text = "([0-9])( )([A-Za-zÆæØøÅå])"
            .Forward = True
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .Replacement.Text = "\1^s\3"
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Next myStoryRange

Comment: @Casper - I tested it in O365 and it works perfectly. But then again I don't use Track Changes, so that could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks alot for all the help Timothy Rylatt, it must be the Track Change like you say.
It is kinda strange if I test "\1AAA\3" on "3 e" I get "3eAAA", "\1AAAA\3" gives the result "3AeAAA" and  "\1AAAAA\3" gets the result "3AAeAAA". Don't know what I can use it for but strange. I must go for the solution you suggested in 3.