# Recognize duplicate headings/chapters from Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, docx, word-2010

I have a big word document. Now I'm searching for a solution which can show me if there are duplicate chapters/headings. When one is found I want the name (and perhaps the page number). Later I want to delete the duplicate chapter by myself.

The heading has no numeration and is a stylesheet (Heading 1).

I thought a VBA script would do that, but I have never used it. How can one do that?

This is how I got so far:

```
Sub FindDuplicates()
    Dim DocPara As Paragraph
    Dim DocPara2 As Paragraph

    For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Left(DocPara.Range.Style, Len("Überschrift 1")) = "Überschrift 1" Then
            For Each DocPara2 In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
                If Left(DocPara.Range.Style, Len("Überschrift 1")) = "Überschrift 1" Then
                     Debug.Print DocPara.Range.Text
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But it never gets finished. Don't know if it's an error in my code or VBA isn't able to handle the amount of data (> 400 pages). Perhaps someone could help.

Comment: [Getting the headings from a Word document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document) might be a good place to start for looking at all the headings.

Comment: If you are actually looking for a manual (code-free) solution, you can consider (a) inserting a ToC that picks up Heading 1 paragraphs, (b) select the result and press ctrl-shift-F9 to replace the ToC field by its result, (c) use the A-Z sort button in Home->Paragraphs to sort (d) inspect the results for duplicates, which should now be next to each other. But that's really a SuperUser question.