# Identify Paragraph content with certain outline level

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro which pass through paragraphs of a word document. This code is intended to pass the paragraph, identify its outline level and retrieve the content when the desired paragraph outline level is found. With this information, I'm populating a listbox that will allow users to choose from what point they want to export some text in a document.

This functionality is working, however, I'm looking for a way to improve its speed. Right now I'm handling a document with 5678 paragraphs, and it is taking over 30 minutes to process all the information. Do you have any suggestion?

I had tried to approaches without having success:

1 - I've tried to use the object TableOfContents, however I was not able to have a clean information and differentiate outline levels from the paragraphs.

2 - I've tried to adapt the code from here [Getting the headings from a Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document), specially because of the use of the command _docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading), also with no success

Here there is the image of the form, and the code I'm using.
[image: Form of execution]

```
Sub ProcessHeaders()
Dim j As Long
Dim Paragraph_Number() As Variant
Dim Paragraph_Content() As Variant
Dim Paragraph_Mapping() As Variant
j = 1
With UserForm1
If .ComboBox4.ListCount > 0 Then
    .ComboBox4.Clear
End If

For i = 1 To wordDoc.Paragraphs.Count
If wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i).OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel1 _
Or wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i).OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel2 _
Or wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i).OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel3 _
Or wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i).OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel4 Then
If wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i).Range.ListFormat.ListString <> "" Then
    ReDim Preserve Paragraph_Number(j)
    ReDim Preserve Paragraph_Content(j)
    Paragraph_Content(j) = wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i).Range.ListFormat.ListString & " " & Trim(Left(wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i).Range.Text, (Len(wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i).Range.Text) - 1)))
    Paragraph_Number(j) = i
    j = j + 1
End If
End If
Next i

    ReDim Preserve Paragraph_Mapping(1 To UBound(Paragraph_Content), 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(Paragraph_Number)
    Paragraph_Mapping(i, 0) = Paragraph_Content(i)
    Paragraph_Mapping(i, 1) = Paragraph_Number(i)

    Next i

.ComboBox4.List = Paragraph_Mapping
End With
End Sub
```

Edit 1 - I Achieve to reduce the time from 32 minutes to 8 minutes of execution with the code below. Any suggestions to improve even more? Thanks in advance

```
Sub ProcessHeaders()
Dim j As Long
Dim thisOutlineLevel As WdOutlineLevel
Dim thisHeader As String
Dim thisList As String
Dim ParagraphCount As Long

Dim Paragraph_Number_Base() As Variant
Dim Paragraph_Content_Base() As Variant
Dim Paragraph_ListItem_Base() As Variant

Dim ParagraphContent() As Variant
Dim ParagraphNumber() As Variant
Dim Paragraph_Mapping() As Variant

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String



j = 1
With UserForm1
If .ComboBox4.ListCount > 0 Then
    .ComboBox4.Clear
End If

ParagraphCount = wordDoc.Paragraphs.Count

ReDim Paragraph_Content_Base(ParagraphCount + 1)
ReDim Paragraph_ListItem_Base(ParagraphCount + 1)
ReDim Paragraph_Number_Base(ParagraphCount + 1)


StartTime = Timer
For i = 1 To ParagraphCount
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
UserForm1.Label7.Caption = "Reading Paragraphs.  " & Format(i / ParagraphCount, "0%") & " | Total of Paragraphs Found: " & ParagraphCount & " | Time Elapsed: " _
& MinutesElapsed & " Minutes"
With wordDoc.Paragraphs.Item(i)
    Select Case .OutlineLevel
        Case wdOutlineLevelBodyText
            GoTo ResumeNext
        Case wdOutlineLevel1, wdOutlineLevel2, wdOutlineLevel3, wdOutlineLevel4
            Paragraph_Content_Base(i) = .Range.Text
            Paragraph_ListItem_Base(i) = .Range.ListFormat.ListString
            Paragraph_Number_Base(i) = i
    End Select
End With

ResumeNext:
Next i
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
UserForm1.Label7.Caption = ParagraphCount & " read on " & MinutesElapsed & " Minutes. Now, identifying the Headers"

For i = 0 To UBound(Paragraph_Content_Base)
    If Paragraph_Content_Base(i) <> "" And Paragraph_ListItem_Base(i) <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve ParagraphContent(j)
        ReDim Preserve ParagraphNumber(j)
        ParagraphContent(j) = Trim(Paragraph_ListItem_Base(i)) & " " & Trim(Left(Paragraph_Content_Base(i), Len(Paragraph_Content_Base(i)) - 1))
        ParagraphNumber(j) = Paragraph_Number_Base(i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i


Erase Paragraph_Content_Base
Erase Paragraph_ListItem_Base
Erase Paragraph_Number_Base

    ReDim Preserve Paragraph_Mapping(1 To UBound(ParagraphContent), 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(ParagraphNumber)
        Paragraph_Mapping(i, 0) = ParagraphContent(i)
        Paragraph_Mapping(i, 1) = ParagraphNumber(i)
    Next i

.ComboBox4.List = Paragraph_Mapping
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
UserForm1.Label7.Caption = "Identifying Headers: " & j & " identified. Total Time: " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes"
End With
```

Edit 2 - With the Help of Cindy, the code which was initially running in 32 minutes right now is running on 32 seconds. Here is the final Code.

```
Sub ProcessHeaders()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim lstFormat As Word.ListFormat
    Dim paraNr() As Variant
    Dim paraContent() As Variant
    Dim counter As Long, paraIndex As Long

    Dim Paragraph_Mapping() As Variant
    Dim ParagraphCount As Long
    Dim i, j As Long

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim StartRealTime As Date
    Dim MinutesElapsed As String

    With UserForm1
    If .ComboBox4.ListCount > 0 Then
        .ComboBox4.Clear
    End If

    counter = 1
    paraIndex = 1
    i = 0
    j = 1
    StartTime = Timer
    StartRealTime = Now
    Set rng = wordDoc.Content
    ParagraphCount = rng.ListParagraphs.Count

    For Each para In rng.ListParagraphs
        i = i + 1
        Set lstFormat = para.Range.ListFormat
        MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
        .Label7.Caption = "Reading Paragraphs.  " & Format(i / ParagraphCount, "0%") & " | Total of Paragraphs Found: " & ParagraphCount & _
        " | Start Time: " & StartRealTime & " | Time Elapsed: " & MinutesElapsed & " Minutes"
        'CheckOutLine = rng.ListParagraphs.Item(1).OutlineLevel
                If lstFormat.ListString <> "" And Len(lstFormat.ListString) >= 2 Then
                    ReDim Preserve paraNr(counter)
                    ReDim Preserve paraContent(counter)
                    paraContent(counter) = lstFormat.ListString & " " _
                                           & Trim(Left(para.Range.Text, (Len(para.Range.Text) - 1)))
                    paraNr(counter) = i
                    wordDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:="ExpContent" & i, Range:=para.Range
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
        paraIndex = paraIndex + 1
    Next
j = 1

    ReDim Preserve Paragraph_Mapping(1 To UBound(paraNr), 1)
    For i = UBound(paraNr) To 1 Step -1
        Paragraph_Mapping(j, 0) = paraContent(i)
        Paragraph_Mapping(j, 1) = paraNr(i)
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    .ComboBox4.List = Paragraph_Mapping
    MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    .Label7.Caption = "Identifying Headers: " & j & " identified. Total Time: " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes"
    End With

'
'    For counter = 1 To UBound(paraNr)
'        Debug.Print paraNr(counter) & vbTab & paraContent(counter)
'    Next
End Sub
```

And After the user choose the paragraph, the bookmarks are being managed by this call

```
With objWord.Selection
        BookmarkID = "ExpContent" & PositionReference
        wordDoc.Bookmarks(BookmarkID).Select
       .InsertParagraphBefore
End With
```

[image: Form of Execution 1]

Once again, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the fastest approach is going to be looping only the numbered paragraphs, rather than all paragraphs. This can be done using the `ListParagraphs` object. For example:

```
Sub IdOutlineLevels()
    Dim rng As word.Range
    Dim para As word.Paragraph
    Dim lstFormat As word.ListFormat
    Dim paraNr() As Variant
    Dim paraContent() As Variant
    Dim counter As Long, paraIndex As Long

    counter = 1
    paraIndex = 1
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.content
    For Each para In rng.ListParagraphs
        Set lstFormat = para.Range.ListFormat
        Select Case lstFormat.ListLevelNumber
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4
                If lstFormat.ListString <> "" Then
                    ReDim Preserve paraNr(counter)
                    ReDim Preserve paraContent(counter)
                    paraContent(counter) = lstFormat.ListString & " " _
                                           & Trim(Left(para.Range.Text, (Len(para.Range.Text) - 1)))
                    paraNr(counter) = paraIndex
                    counter = counter + 1
                    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="ExpContent" & counter, Range:=para.Range
                End If
            Case Else
        End Select
        paraIndex = paraIndex + 1
    Next

    For counter = 1 To UBound(paraNr)
        Debug.Print paraNr(counter) & vbTab & paraContent(counter)
    Next
End Sub
```

Rather than relying on the index number of the paragraph in the document to locate the paragraph again I've added bookmarks to each of the paragraphs using the same "counter" as the paragraph number. This is the technique Word, itself, uses for cross-referencing.

Comment: Hi Cindy. Thank you very much for your help. I've made some tests here and got your point. Didn't knew that was possible to bookmark the Headers. I'll work in my code and try to fit this method with the structure I already have. Keep you posted how it works. Thanks

Comment: WOAH, Thank you so much for your insights, Cindy. Just made a few tweaks and what was being executed in 32 minutes right now is running on surprising 17 seconds or less.

Comment: Thanks once again. I was wondering where the H#$% was this button.