# Can I get Range from ReferenceType in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make a makro that copies tables from a generated document into a chapter of an existing document. Using the accepted answer to this question [Getting the headings from a Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274814/getting-the-headings-from-a-word-document), I managed to find the chapter where I want to copy the tables. The problem is that the makro access the headings through GetCrossReferenceItems. The return value is saved in a Variance astrHeadings.

It seems that I need a Range object with start and end of the chapter to add a table. Can I get the range start from the Variance astrHeadings?

Comment: You will likely need to search from the found reference to the next heading type (possibly at the same heading level?).  That will give you a range.  Then you can enumerate the tables in the range.

Comment: Finding what heading a table is under is fairly straightforward. And, provided the destination heading has the same heading level & text as the source, finding the correct heading there is simple. What isn't so simple is finding where under the new heading to place the table being replicated if there is other content below that heading. So the issue becomes one of how you will identify the precise location under the destination heading to place the table. DO you have a table you're replacing, a bookmark, or some other identifying feature for the code to use as a reference point?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Yes I actually I want to update existing tables so it might be easier looking for them and create new tables on the same range. It seems easier to do things with Table objects - there seems to be at least some documentation. Is it just me or are the VBA docs extremely brief?

Comment: In which case, the question arises as to whether the headings are at all relevant. If, for example, it's always a specific table in the source document (e.g. table 4), and another specific table in the destination document (e.g. table 5), one need only know which table it is in each.

Comment: Hm, I tried the iterate-tables-approach earlier but I had a problem with the tables, maybe they are slightly corrupt since it's generated tables with merged cells.

Comment: Now I save the range of the existing table, delete the table and add a new one using the saved range. The problem is that the new table is created with a heading/section in every cell. Is there some problem with the range? Sorry, I'm a noob - I'm used to coding but not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

For example, supposing the only the destination document is open, table 2 from the source document replaces table 1 in the destination document:

```
Sub XferTbl()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, RngSrc As Range
Dim DocTgt As Document, RngTgt As Range
Set DocTgt = ActiveDocument
With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
  If .Show = -1 Then
    .AddToMru = False
    .ReadOnly = True
    .Visible = False
    .Update
    Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument
  End If
End With
If DocSrc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set RngSrc = DocSrc.Tables(2).Range
Set RngTgt = DocTgt.Tables(1).Range
With RngTgt
  .Tables(1).Range.Delete
  .FormattedText = RngSrc.FormattedText
End With
DocSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you only want to transfer data from particular cells, see, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/21403-copy-table-content-between-documents.html